# Discord py sending random images from google

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently started learning python and discord.py trying to make a code that sends a random image from google to However I can't seem to figure out how to set up the code or it's written wrong

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Images(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  gis = GoogleImagesSearch('...', '...')

  _search_params = {
    'q': 'razorcrest',
    'num': 10,
    'safe': 'off',
    'fileType': 'png',
    'imgType': 'photo',
    'imgSize': 'large',
    'imgDominantColor': 'black',
    'imgColorType': 'color',
    'rights': 'cc_publicdomain'
  }

  gis.search(search_params=_search_params)

  gis.search(search_params=_search_params, path_to_dir='/path/')

  gis.search(search_params=_search_params, path_to_dir='/path/', width=500, height=500)

  gis.search(search_params=_search_params)
  for image in gis.results():
    image.download('/path/')
    image.resize(500, 500)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Images(client))
```

What should I do with this code?
or how to make a code for random images from google?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lorem picsum` api.
**Usage**
set this url: `https://picsum.photos/200/300` as the source for your image.
the api will give you a random image whenever you visit the url.
You can also set how wide or how high you want your image to be in the url params